# Multipart form-data using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am trying to use zend framework to post multipart/form-data , to send xml and files

```
$uri = 'http://...';

$update = new Zend_Http_Client();
$update->setUri($uri);
$update->setHeaders('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');

$xml = ' <man>'.
         '<man-id>12</man-id>'.
         '<man-name>Smith</man-name>'.
         '<man-tall>186</man-tall>'.
       '</man>';

$response = $update->encodeFormData('a','file', $xml,'./src/server/TVP.jpg',array("Content-Transfer-Encoding" => "binary"));
```

How i can exactly use this function ( encodeFormData() ) to do this post ???
or if there any other way that i can use to post ???

Answer (score 0):

To send XML you can use setRawData() like:

```
$xml = ' <man>'.
         '<man-id>12</man-id>'.
         '<man-name>Smith</man-name>'.
         '<man-tall>186</man-tall>'.
       '</man>';

$update->setRawData($xml);
```

This is in the [Zend Framework Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html) about half way down the page under "Sending Raw POST Data"

Hope this helps!